# CYPRESS - How to get a user's token to acess other tab in the same Cypress window, putting cy.visist(URL + TOKEN)

Tags: testing, tabs, window, cypress

I have a system that logs in via a login and password. After I do a login I have one functionality where I click and it goes to a new Browser Tab.
I tried to get a button click and go to this tab, but Cypress loses control of the application and opens a new window, not opening the tab on the same Cypress window.
When I tried to put  the tab URL on `cy.visit` to manually open the tab, the system doesn't open this tab, and returns to login page because the  user's token is shown  on URL of the new tab that I want to access. For this reason I can't visit this tab from `cy.visit`, because this URL can be dynamic.

How I can get the token to try visit 'URL + token' from website and open this tab on the same Cypress window? Is there some different way to open this new tab on Cypress test?

Answer (score 0):

Can you bootstrap your test data in such a way that token isn't dynamic? Or is known at the time of running the tests?

Comment: The token is created when I log in. So I can't define the token or anything.
For example, the site I access to log in is "www.abc.com/home.do", but when the system opens a new tab, when I access functionality, the URL is "www.abc.com/home.do?t=TOKEN", so I can't put the URL in cy.visit, because the token can be different every time I log in. We are using the homoloagation environment.

Answer (score 0):

First, ask the developers where can you get the token from after the login. Usually it's stored either in a cookie or in local storage.

In the test, perform the login first, then read the token and then navigate to the URL of the tab page using the token you've read as the query string.

HTH